# Rails I18n translate multiple line text block in a maintainable way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have many complex structured html + text in my Rails application and don't know how to translate these in a maintainable way. Whats the best way to approach this.

Consider this haml html block:

```
%h3.grey
  You can set your profile so that:

%h4
  %ol
    %li
      Some line blabla
    %li
      Other users cannot find you
    %li
      Your profile appears as if it's deleted
.clear
Or
.clear
%br
```

- I dont want to use language partials it would clutter up and is terrible on partial change
- rather not use 1 string translations to translate the above block

**What would be a easy, maintainable way to translate the above?** Any thoughts suggestions welcome would love to hear how others have tackled this, thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translation of the whole block with included html tags - in this case you have to add "_html" suffix to translation variable. Don't sure it works with haml.
But for me the best way is to use translations for each string.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like the following

```
=t(:p3_html).each_line do |line|
  %li= |line|
```

Which should give you this:

```
%li Line1
%li Line2
%li Line3
```